# No. of strings between 2 given strings in lexicographical order

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have been given 2 strings namely A and B and I have to find the no. of strings lying between A and B where the inbetween lying strings must be formed only from the characters of A.

Another restriction is that each letter has to be used exactly once.

For example :

A->abc

B->ddd

Ans=5

From string abc, the strings obtained are acb, bac, bca, cab, cba, all of them are larger than abc, but smaller than ddd. So the answer is 5.

Also, it may be the case that a given character in the string may repeat any number of times.ie- the below case is also included in the problem statement.

A->abacaba

B->ubuduba

Ans=64

How do I find the no. of such strings ?

Comment: In your example, you seem to add another restriction that you don't mention in the problem statement: That each character in $A$ must appear exactly once in each string. If this is correct, please add it to the problem statement.

Comment: @joriki But interestingly B is ddd. I guess either a mistake by the OP in not considering strings in which elements appear twice, or at least an ambiguous question?

Comment: @joriki Is the problem clear now ?

Comment: No. The restriction that each letter has to be used exactly once is still not mentioned.

Comment: @joriki   now Added.

Comment: We generally like to hear about the sources of problems. This is particularly true when the problems come from contest sites. In the present case, [the contest appears to be finished](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/895/D) (if I'm interpreting the status provided at the top right correctly), so the question doesn't violate our [contest problem policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy). However, we could have saved a lot of time clarifying the question if you'd directly linked to the very clear problem statement on the site.

Comment: @joriki After that you have got the link of the question and me not breaking any policy, I hope that the question is expected to be answered by someone !!

Comment: @Jacob: Well, it's a coding contest, not a math contest. Usually problems for coding contests are designed such that you actually have to code something and it's hard to calculate the result just by applying math.

Comment: @joriki But, it surely is a good application of permutations&combinations. I just need the basic mathematical logic behind solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{\text{a},\ldots,\text{z}\}$ be our alphabet, $S^*$ the set of words over that alphabet, $\epsilon$ the empty word.
First we solve the following problem

> Given a map $f\colon S\to\Bbb N_0$, compute the number $N(f)$ of words $\xi\in S^*$ such that each $x\in S$ occurs exactly $f(x)$ times in $\xi$.

This is easy. One readily finds
$$N(f)=\frac{(\sum_{x\in S}f(x))!}{\prod_{x\in S}f(x)!}.$$

Next, we use recursion (on the length of $\beta$) to solve the following task

> Given a map $f\colon S\to\Bbb N_0$ and a word $\beta\in S^*$, compute the number $N(f,\beta)$ of words $\xi\in S^*$ such that $\xi<\beta$ and each $x\in S$ occurs exactly $f(x)$ times in $\xi$.

If $\beta=\epsilon$, then clearly $$N(f,\beta)=0.$$
Otherwise, write $\beta=b\beta'$ with $b\in S$, $\beta'\in S^*$.
For $x\in S$ with $f(x)>0$ define
$$f_x(t)=\begin{cases}f(t)-1&t=x\\f(t)&t\ne x\end{cases}.$$
Then one sees that
$$ N(f,\beta)=\sum_{x<b,\atop f(x)>0} N(f_x)+\begin{cases}N(f_b,\beta')&f(b)>0\\0&f(b)=0\end{cases}.$$

---

Now finally

> Given $\alpha,\beta\in S^*$, the number of words $\xi\in S^*$ such that $\alpha<\xi<\beta$ and each letter $x$ occurs in $\xi$ and in $\alpha$ with the same frequency $f(x)$, is $$N(f,\beta)-N(f,\alpha)-1. $$